# How can I modify my PHP code using DomDocument, to remove the parentheses and the words they contain?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I am trying to remove with `DomDocument` and the `str_ireplace` function, all the `span` tags having the `class` attribute containing `language-indicator` which are often words in parentheses including: `(d)`, `(en)`.

**It works** BUT *the problem is that it only removes the words that are in the parenthesis: `d`, `en`. AND does not remove the parentheses themselves at all: `()`.*

```
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $parser = new DOMDocument();
    $parser->loadHTMLFile("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Zuckerberg");
    $get_span_tags = $parser->getElementsByTagName("span");
    foreach ($get_span_tags as $get_span_tag) {
            if (stripos($get_span_tag->getAttribute('class'), "indicateur-langue") !== false) {
                $get_infoxbox_span = $parser->saveHTML($get_span_tag);
                $wikipediaInfoboxTable = str_ireplace($get_infoxbox_span, "", $wikipediaInfoboxTable);
            }
        }
        
echo $wikipediaInfoboxTable;
```

So **how can I modify my code to also remove the parentheses and the words they contain because currently the words are removed and the parentheses `()` are not ???**

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: The above seems incomplete - where and how is `$get_span_tags` defined?

Comment: I just modified the code by adding the variable `$get_span_tags`. Thanks. I expect you to help me.

Comment: If you use `DOMXPath` you would be able to identify the relevant nodes directly

Comment: How to use DOMXPath is my cas please ??? I never use DOMXPath. So, give me an example of usage in my case please.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought that using an `XPath` to explicitly identify the nodes of interest would be easier that the initial approach. Rather than using `str_replace` etc you could remove the span elements completely from the DOM?!

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile( 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Zuckerberg' );

# create the XPath object
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

# create the query to find spans with class as specified
$expr='//span[ @class="indicateur-langue" ]';

# query the dom and iterate through results
$col=$xp->query( $expr );
if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node ){
        $node->parentNode->removeChild( $node );
    }
    
    #create a copy of the modified HTML
    $html=$dom->saveHTML();
    
    # show the result?
    printf('<textarea cols=100 rows=20>%s</textarea>', print_r( $html ,true ) );
}
```

Comment: **It doesn't work at all.** The parentheses are still present despite using this sample `xpath` code you just gave me. I really need your help.

Comment: It does work - it happily removes **all** the span elements with class `"indicateur-langue"` ~ You have a look at the printed content within the textarea and there should be no `span.indicateur-langue` there